# Having trouble understanding the proof for Fourier Transform Scaling Property

Tags: fourier-transform

Starting from Plancherel's Theorem:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(k)e^{ikx}dk ...(1)
$$
$$
F(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx ...(2)
$$
I need to show the scaling property holds:

If $h(x) = f(ax)$ then,
$$
H(k) = \frac{1}{|a|}F(\frac{k}{a})
$$
where $H(k)$ is the Fourier Transform of $h(x)$

I understand the absolute value comes from taking both the cases a > 0 and a < 0, but I am confused on the step after you make the substitution $u = ax$.

$$
H(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(ax)e^{-ikx}dx
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)e^{-iku/a}d(u/a) ...(3)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{a}F(\frac{k}{a})
$$

From the original Plancherel's Theorem (2), the integral for $F(k)$ is taken with respect to $x$ **and** $f$ is a function of $x$.

In the proof however, the integral is taken with respect to $u/a$, **but** $f$ is a function of $u$.

How does one deduce that the expression in (3) is an inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{a}F(\frac{k}{a})$?

Comment: This is a mathematics question rather than a physics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (3), pull the factor $1/a$ out of the integral, and define $k' :=k/a$. Then you have
\begin{equation}\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u~f(u)~e^{-ik'u}~ = \frac{1}{a}F(k') = \frac{1}{a}F\left(\frac{k}{a}\right)\end{equation}